# Executing Stored procedure in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I'm new to SSRS and I have a very simple question: I am executing a stored procedure in SSRS and generating some results. Does the SSRS keeps hitting the SP continuously in the backend even when the SQL Server Data tool is closed, as I am seeing SP's query execution in a DMV result.

Comment: the stored procedure is executed when the report is loaded. the only exception is a schedule: if you schedule report execution then the stored procedure is executed when scheduled.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Paolo

Answer (score 0):

SSRS calls the Stored Procedure only when instructed to when a report is run.  If you request a new rendering of the report, the SP will be called again.

You need to ensure that there are no subscriptions for this report running, or other users commanding requests of the report that you are unaware of (users are logged in the `ExecutionLog3` table).

Answer (score 0):

SSRS only run stored procedure/query when we run our report after deployment, other then that no query or stored procedure executes at the back end by its on.

Other than that we have a concepts of subscription in SSRS, which allows us to subscribe SSRS report after a desired time interval (daily, monthly or any other criteria). In this case whenever our report runs after given time interval the corresponding query/stored procedure will be executed.